# Do review audits become more frequent after a ban?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've just come off of a 4-day review ban, and saw a dramatically higher number of review audits showing up for a little while when I was going through reopen votes - averaging one audit per six questions.

Is this intentional, or is it an anomaly? I can totally see the reasoning if it's intentional, just got me curious whether it's actually a feature or not.

Comment: [Could just be random](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: They aren't exactly going to publicly reveal their audit algorithm, for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: Audits like the one that tripped you up can be spotted by opening the question under review in a new tab. Don’t lower your quality standards just in an attempt to pass audits, please.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "lowering quality standards", but I do know audits can be opened in a new tab and checked. Isn't that subverting the system or something, though?

Comment: No, it’s not subverting the system. Audits are supposed to catch reviewers who are reviewing robotically and just clicking buttons without paying attention. If you’re clicking through to check the post, you are obviously paying attention and not robo-reviewing. What I meant about lowering your standards is the obvious meaning. You failed an audit because you thought a question was unsalvageable, when it was actually well-received. I don’t want you to lower your standards for what is a good question as a result of that particular audit.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'll put your advice to practice; I can see how it would lead to better reviews in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your audit performance impacts your audit encounters.

[An answer on MSE by m0sa♦ in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231181/178816) states the adoption of [Shog's proposal on that same post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183017/178816):

> We could certainly show them less often for folks with a good track record... and more often for folks with a bad one. What do you think? Maybe,
>
> - 100% success rate for, say, the past 20 audits gets you at least 30 reviews before the next one,
> - Anything under 50% rolls the dice every review.

The [rolls the dice note references another Shog9 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168073/178816):

> 5% chance of being audited starting 5 reviews after your last audit. You probably won't see any fewer audits, but you should see more of them in the queues you're actually most active in. And your chances of being quarantined will depend more heavily on past behavior in the queue you're being audited in
>
> Still TODO: make this more heavily dependent on your recent failure rate.

While there was [some discussion in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274464/178816) with regards to "dialing back audit frequency", there doesn't seem to have been any action to that effect.

Answer (score 7):

They increase in frequency if you fail an audit and conversely [decrease in frequency when you pass one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170816/188189). Since the main reason to be banned is because you failed enough audits that's why you're seeing a correlation.